# Solving simple transcendental equations

Tags: transcendental-equations

Is there a way (excluding solving by graphing the two functions) to solve an equation like $\sin x = \ln x$ ?

Comment: If I correctly understand the sense of your question, I would say that there is no way.

Comment: There is at least one point of intersection for $x>0$ as demonstrated in [Graph](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=graph+sin(x)+and+%5Cln(x)). One of the many numerical methods would have to be used to get the best reasonable solution of the equation.

Answer (score 2):

$$\sin x=\log x$$
$$x=e^{\sin x}$$
so
$$x=e^{\sin e^{\sin e^{\sin e^{\sin .......}}}}=2.219...$$
or you can use Newton's Method
$$x_n=x_{n+1}-\frac{y_n}{y'_n}$$
so that 
$$y=\sin x-\log x$$
$$y'=\cos x-\frac{1}{x}$$

Answer (score 1):

If you mean finding a closed form by mean of elementary functions: in this example, no. By elementary, I mean trig, log, exponential and their inverses, and of course the four operations and the extraction of roots (this last operation can be computed as $a^b=\exp(b\log a)$ anyway). Sometimes there is a solution, it depends entirely on the equation.

If you mean proving there is a solution: yes, it's possible, mainly by studying the variations of the functions.

If you mean finding an approximate solution: there are **many** ways. The most common is maybe [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method), at least for such a simple example.

Notice that finding a closed form is generally impossible. Often it's also not a good idea. For instance, it's relatively easy to solve a polynomial equation of degree $4$. However, the closed form is not necessarily well behaved numerically, and it may be wiser to use a numerical method if you want a numerical value, even though there is actually a "formula".

Notice also that the equation (or another equation with no closed form solution) may define a "special function", that you can then use as if it was a closed form solution. For instance, it's common to define the solution of $xe^x=a$ to be the [Lambert $W$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), so the solution is simply $x=W(a)$. But this seemingly closed form actually hides a computation that can be done only numerically. It's still interesting to do that because you can study the function $W$, its variations, find a Taylor series expansion, and many more.

So, what do you want to do exactly?

Comment: I meant finding the exact solution, not the approximate. Thank you for your answer !